# Space / time requirements for ISO-Prolog processor compliance

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

All implementations of the functional programming language [scheme](/questions/tagged/scheme) are required to perform [tail-call-optimization](/questions/tagged/tail-call-optimization) whenever it is applicable.

Does [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog) have this one and / or similar requirements?

It's clear to me that Prolog processor features like first argument principal functor indexing and atom garbage collection *are* widely adopted, but are *not prescribed* by the ISO standard.

**But what about [prolog-cut](/questions/tagged/prolog-cut)?**

Make believe that some Prolog system gets the semantics right, but does not guarantee that ...

```
rep.
rep :- !, rep.
rep.

?- rep, false.
```

... can run forever with constant stack space?

Could that system still be ISO-Prolog compliant?

Comment: I think these type of questions are great but they are at another level beyond me. If only they were on another forum for more advanced Prolog then I would haven't to spend so much time looking for them here.

Comment: @GuyCoder. Let's keep the discussion here at SO, for the Prolog community is dispersed enough already... in the meantime, have U read https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog-second-edition yet (out of press, free pdf download)?

Comment: I have that book and `The Craft of Prolog` and the ISO standard. I know, I should read them more. :)

Comment: @repeat: I believe from what you said that you indeed have read the standard. If it does not mention those requirements then a prolog processor shouldn't be requiered to meet them in order to be complaint.

Comment: @repeat: Regarding those other features that are widely adopted... GNU Prolog which is supposedly almost ISO-Compliant does not have atom garbage collection (there is some code to do that but for some reason it is not included by default when you build the processor).

Comment: @gusbro. To be perfectly honest, I'm still have not read it front to back, so that's why I'm asking:) Regarding GNU Prolog... I think that Ulrich Neumerkel's big page http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_testing refers to *syntax* (basically read_term and write_term). Other pages in his web of pages http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/ are about DCGs, builtin predicates, evaluable functors, and other important details, but I couldn't deduce if (or to what degree) GNU Prolog is more conformant than, say, SICStus Prolog or not.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are reading a standard, first look at its scope (domaine d'application, область применения, Anwendungsbereich).  Thus whether or not the standard applies to what you want to know.  And in 13211-1:1995, 1 Scope there is a note:

> NOTE - This part of ISO/IEC 13211 does not specify:
>
> > a) the size or complexity of Prolog text that will exceed the
> > capacity of any specific data processing system or language
> > processor, or the actions to be taken when the corresponding
> > limits are exceeded;
> >
> > b) the minimal requirements of a data processing system
> > that is capable of supporting an implementation of a Prolog
> > processor;
>
> ...

Strictly speaking, this is only a note.  But if you leaf through the standard, you will realize that there are no such requirements.  For a similar situation see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25125542/772868).

Further, resource errors (7.12.2 h) and system errors may occur at "any stage of execution".

Historically, the early implementations of DEC10 did not contain last call optimizations and a lot of effort was invested by programmers to either use failure driven loops or enable logarithmic stack usage.

In your example `rep`, a conforming system may run out of space.  And that overflow may be signaled with a resource error, but even that is not required since the system might bail out with a system error. What is more irritating to me is the following program

```
rep2 :- rep2.
rep2.
```

Even this program may run infinitely without ever running out of space! And this although nobody cuts away the extra choice point.

In summary, recall that conformance with a standard is just a precondition for a working system.